# Explicitly pass prefix to BCP (bulk copy) utility for exporting file to MS SQL Sever table

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Is it possible to pass prefix as parameter to **BCP** utility running non-interactively? There are some keys used for non-interactive modes (*-c, -n, -N, -w, -6*). I mostly interested in *-n/-N* because they get types from sql server when I exporting file. But they use default value for prefix, while I need it to be 0.

Comment: I have the same problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80920/header-is-added-when-exporting-column-of-type-image-with-bcp-to-files

Answer (score 0):

The solution seem to be to first execute BCP manually, set prefix to 0 in the user dialog. And then use the generated .fmt-file as in this command:

```
BCP "SELECT my_column FROM my_table WHERE my_id = 11" 
queryout "C:\bcpdir\bcpout.xml" -T -f "C:\bcpdir\bcp.fmt"
```

Solution by Jonas (above link) worked for me